# KeyEventArgs.Key to char

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keyeventargs

Is there any way to convert WPF's `KeyEventArgs.Key` to `Char`?

I tried to use `KeyInterop`:

```
var x = (Char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
```

For numbers and letters it works fine, but for other characters it doesn't.
E.g. for `OemComma` it returns '1/4' instead of ','.

I need it to prevent user of inputting into `TextBox` any characters except numbers and separators (i.e. commas or periods).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825820/how-to-capture-the-character-on-different-locale-keyboards-in-wpf-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a character in to equivalent System.Windows.Input.Key Enum value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544141/how-to-convert-a-character-in-to-equivalent-system-windows-input-key-enum-value)

Comment: Try `KeyConverter.ConvertToString` instead

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: the comment below found the original http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826175/187650

Found this somewhere that I've forgotten. Still using it, not sure what holes it has, but it's worked as far as I know.

```
public static class KeyEventUtility
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    public enum MapType : uint
    {
        MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0x0,
        MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK = 0x1,
        MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x2,
        MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX = 0x3,
    }
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern int ToUnicode(
        uint wVirtKey,
        uint wScanCode,
        byte[] lpKeyState,
        [Out, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 4 )] 
        StringBuilder pwszBuff,
        int cchBuff,
        uint wFlags );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern bool GetKeyboardState( byte[] lpKeyState );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey( uint uCode, MapType uMapType );

    public static char GetCharFromKey( Key key )
    {
        char ch = ' ';

        int virtualKey = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey( key );
        var keyboardState = new byte[256];
        GetKeyboardState( keyboardState );

        uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey( (uint)virtualKey, MapType.MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC );
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( 2 );

        int result = ToUnicode( (uint)virtualKey, scanCode, keyboardState, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity, 0 );
        switch ( result )
        {
        case -1:
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            {
                ch = stringBuilder[0];
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                ch = stringBuilder[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        return ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: for bugs in this code, see the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826175/187650

Answer (score 6):

My first suggestion would be using **PreviewTextInput** and using the **TextCompositionEventArgs**.
However this 'eats' the space-characters.
For this 'space'-issue see:

- [How can I prevent input controls from stealing the space character from the TextCompositionManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053533/how-can-i-prevent-input-controls-from-stealing-the-space-character-from-the-text)
- [Why does PreviewTextInput not handle spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971559/why-does-previewtextinput-not-handle-spaces)

another solution would be using the **KeyConverter** in a **KeyUp** event:

```
  KeyConverter kc = new KeyConverter();
  var str = kc.ConvertToString(e.Key);
```

For **WPF**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter(v=vs.110).aspx 
For **Winforms**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter.aspx

Note that KeyConverter will give you the string "Space" instead of " ". (same for "Esc" when pressing the escape key.

Another WPF solution is using this in the **KeyUp** event:

```
((char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key))
```

Comment: That `KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey` does not help either, when pressing numpad 1 (`NumPad1`) it will get char 'a' (byte: 97).

Answer (score 2):

Why such approach? There are different ways of preventing users from performing such input. For example, define an event-handler for the `TextBox.TextChanged`-event and when the input is not a decimal or a separator, revoke the input.

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args){
//args contains a property `Changes` where you can see what happened
//check for invalid characters and revoke them
}
```

See [TextChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.aspx) and the [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx).

Comment: I solved that problem with [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.UIELEMENT.PREVIEWTEXTINPUT);k(VS.XAMLEDITOR);k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true). But thanks anyway.