# Get Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs Key Enum int value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to capture a Key Press and get the `e.Key` Enum `int` value.

---

This captures and displays the key that was pressed.

**XAML**

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnDPad_L"
              Content="{Binding DPad_L_Text}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="80,172,0,0" 
              Height="30"
              Width="30" 
              PreviewKeyDown="btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

**C#**

```
private void btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int keyEnum = (int)e.Key; // Capture

    MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());   // Letter
    MessageBox.Show(keyEnum.ToString()); // Enum
}
```

---

**Problem**

This gives the `System.Windows.Input` Micrcorosft Keys Enum int values.

[System.Windows.Input.Keys Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=netframework-4.8)

```
W = 66  
A = 44   
S = 62  
D = 47
```

I need the `System.Windows.Forms` `KeyEventArgs` different int values.

[System.Windows.Forms.Keys Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=netframework-4.8)

```
W = 87  
A = 65  
S = 83  
D = 68
```

---

**Errors**

When I try to use `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` I get the errors:

> No overload for 'btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown' matches delegate 'KeyEventHandler'

I try to attach a handler to `Window_Loaded` event:

`btnDPad_L.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs(btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown);`

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Keys'

Comment: Are you in WPF or windows forms? The class for arguments to the event, `KeyEventArgs`, is not an event handler delegate type. You want [`System.Windows.[Input or Forms as appropriate].KeyEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.keydown?view=netframework-4.8) -- or better yet, just add the bare delegate: `btnDPad_L.KeyDown += btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown;`. That'll be fine if it's the correct prototype.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm in WPF. After more research I found how to convert the keys values from `Input` to `Forms` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1153059/6806643

Comment: doesn't sound like it but maybe this is what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071604/3225

Comment: Use this: `Enum.TryParse(e.Key.ToString(), out System.Windows.Forms.Keys winFormsKey)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeyInterop Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyinterop?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to convert WPF keys to WinForms and WinForms keys to WPF.

> KeyInterop Class provides static methods to convert between Win32 Virtual-Keys and the WPF Key enumeration.

Sample:

```
private void btnDPad_L_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var wpfKey = e.Key;
    // Add System.Windows.Forms to references
    var winFormsKey = (Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(wpfKey);
    // TODO: ...
}
```