# WPF, How to detect Spacebar press in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In WPF, I have a RichTextBox with a flow document inside. I need to know when the user presses a spacebar. The code below works and shows a messagebox each time a key is pressed but not for spacebar. If you press F e.g. a messagebox with F is displayed but when space is pressed the caret just moves to the next position.

```
private void RichTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Text);
            }
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the space character by handling the `PreviewKeyDown` or `PreviewKeyUp` events like this:

```
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
    {
        // The user pressed the space bar
    }
}
```

As to why the `PreviewTextInput` event ignores the space character, you can find some interesting information in the [Why does PreviewTextInput not handle spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971559/why-does-previewtextinput-not-handle-spaces) post and the links found there.