# How can I turn off default validation in WPF?

Tags: wpf

It seems that WPF has some validation rule which is turned on by default. When I enter non numeric text into the bound textbox and tab out it, a read border shows around it. What is going on here? I Have set ValidatesOnExceptions to false, where is the validation rule coming from? I am using version 4.5.2 of the .Net framework.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="159.206" Width="193.953">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding Foo, ValidatesOnExceptions=False, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                     Width="91" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,48,0,0" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91"/>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code behind

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; } = 42;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *never* set an `int` property to anything else than a valid `int` value.

This "validation", or rather type-safety feature of the programming language, cannot be turned off.

You can however get rid of or customize the the default error *template* if you want to. Just set the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property to an emoty `ControlTemplate`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="{Binding Foo, ValidatesOnExceptions=False, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
        Width="91" Margin="10,10,0,0">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate />
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. What if have a int? and I want blank text to map to null, this doesn't seem to work by default. Do I have to write a custom converter?

Comment: Probably. You need to convert the empty string to null. String.Empty is not a valid int? value.

Answer (score 0):

On app startup, you can add this call to FrameworkCompatibiltyPreferences to disable all textboxes from messing with your input:

```
class App
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {　　　　 
        System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(new Window1());
    }
}
```

If you're using data binding, it appears that the textboxes will still protect against invalid input. A validation error will be shown (default being the red border) and the view model property will not be set with the invalid value. But now you can input whatever string you want. Makes entering decimal values bound to float or double properties MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8)'s excellent answer, for anyone looking to do this for a nullable `int`, you can do as follows;

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <converters:NullableIntToStringConverter x:Key="NullableIntConverter" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<!-- ...snip ... -->
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"              
         Text="{Binding Path=SearchRackNumber,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource NullableIntConverter},ValidatesOnExceptions=False}"
         PreviewTextInput="TxtRackNumber_OnPreviewTextInput"
         PreviewKeyDown="TxtRackNumber_OnPreviewKeyDown">
  <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate />
  </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

**Code Behind**

The events here prevent the user from typing non-numeric characters. In my case, I only cared about positive integer values. Two events are needed to handle most text, and separately, spaces (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099420/1838819) for why).

```
private void TxtRackNumber_OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var numericRegEx = new Regex("^[0-9]{0,10}$");
    e.Handled = !numericRegex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}

private void TxtRackNumber_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // a separate event is needed to handle the space as it doesn't trigger the
    // OnPreviewTextInput event. This is by WPF design to handle IME languages
    // (ones that take more than one key press to enter a character, e.g., Chinese).
    e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
}
```

**Converter**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace YourApp
{
    internal class NullableIntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())) return null;

            var stringValue = value.ToString();
            if (!int.TryParse(stringValue, out int parsed)) return null;

            return parsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simpler solution with minimal code and usable in styles and this works too:

**XAML**

```html
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```