# Whitespace character is not restricted using Regex in KeyDown event in WPF

Tags: c#, textbox, textinput

I'm trying to restrict the first character other than English alphabet, but I'm still able to enter whitespace as first character which is not what I want.
How can I prevent the first character from beeing a whitespace during the typing?

```
private void TbxCode_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex myRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]$");

    if (tbxCode.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        if (!myRegex.IsMatch(e.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cgmsui="clr-namespace:ClassGetMSUI;assembly=ClassGetMSUI">

        <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="tbxCode"
                     Width="100"
                     Height="20"
                     PreviewTextInput="TbxCodeHoraire_PreviewTextInput" />
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Note the issue is not the regex, `^[a-zA-Z]$` only matches a single ASCII letter.

Answer (score 0):

`if (tbxCode.Text.Length == 0)` you're only handling the regex when there is nothing in the text box, you should change it to `if (tbxCode.Text.Length != 0)`.

Also, your regex only allow a single character in the text box. If you want to validate only the fisrt character, it should be `@"^[a-zA-Z]"`;

Comment: I tried to change with your modifications but nothing happend. I still can add a whitespace as first character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
private void TbxCode_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex myRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]$");
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            if (tbxCode.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                if (!myRegex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString()))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to this article :
[Why does PreviewTextInput not handle spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971559/why-does-previewtextinput-not-handle-spaces)